# can't set ALTREP truelength

Tags: r, data.table

I have some code that worked normally untill I updated to R 4.0.2.

```
colnames <- c("Wind")
type <- "Month"
temp <- setDT(airquality)[, lapply(.SD, sum), keyby = Month, .SDcols = colnames]
colnames_new <- paste0(colnames, "_", type)
setnames(temp, c("Month", colnames_new))
setDT(airquality)[, (colnames_new) := temp[i = airquality[, .(Month)], j = -1, on = "Month"]]
```

Now I get the error:

> Error in .shallow(x, cols = cols, retain.key = TRUE) :    can't set
> ALTREP truelength

I use data.table 1.13.0. Does anyone have the same problem?

Comment: Where does `ipcal` come from? `setDT(airquality)` produces an error on my system. `data.table(airquality)` should achieve the intended results.

Comment: sorry, that must also be airquality

Comment: BTW, `setDT` operates on side-effect. While it does return the object with class `data.table`, it also changes that attribute *in place*, so after you first do `setDT(airquality)` in line 3, that frame is a `data.table`, there is no need for `setDT` in line 6. (If you want a *functional* mechanism without side-effect, use `as.data.table(airquality)`, though it doesn't look like that is needed here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is roughly what I might do

```r
library(data.table)
aqDT <- data.table(airquality)
cln <- "Wind" # colnames is a function in base R, better not add confusion
aqDT[, paste0(cln, "_Month") := sum(get(cln)), by = Month]
aqDT

#      Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day Wind_Month
#   1:    41     190  7.4   67     5   1      360.3
#   2:    36     118  8.0   72     5   2      360.3
#   3:    12     149 12.6   74     5   3      360.3
#   4:    18     313 11.5   62     5   4      360.3
#   5:    NA      NA 14.3   56     5   5      360.3
#  ---                                             
# 149:    30     193  6.9   70     9  26      305.4
# 150:    NA     145 13.2   77     9  27      305.4
# 151:    14     191 14.3   75     9  28      305.4
# 152:    18     131  8.0   76     9  29      305.4
# 153:    20     223 11.5   68     9  30      305.4
```

Answer (score 1):

Before any standard dataframe operation (e.g. with dplyr) make sure that you turn datatable into a dataframe

```
mydatatable = as.data.frame(mydatatable) 

# DO your dplyr or standard dataframe operations
# now use setDT(mydatatable) or   mydatatable = as.data.table(mydatatable) 

 mydatatable = as.data.table(mydatatable) 

# do your datatable operations
```

Comment: I have tried that. But, that would mean that every time before I use setDT I have to change to dataframe? Otherwise, the first setDT would work, but with the next the same error occurs. 
I have the feeling that the issue is more related to the size of the data (data is very large).